# My browser doesn't refresh my link to excel with extension htm

Tags: php, html, excel, browser, browser-cache

Good PM,

Below is my code. I've been trying to display my excel file with .htm extension to my browser.
But when I update the bulletin3.htm using excel. My browser doesn't refresh. I have to press Ctrl+f5.

Please hope some one could help me.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">

   <!--<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />-->

   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
   <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
   <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
 ?>

 <iframe id="example_frame" title="Workshop Bulletin" src="bulletin3.htm" height="1000px" width="100%">              
 </iframe>



</body>
</html>`
```

I've tried the this code, not to store cache.

```
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">`
```

Also
using

```
 `<?php
   header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
   header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
  ?>`
```

Comment: Browsers commonly cache html files. The headers you've set only apply to the main page, not the document in the iframe

Comment: You are inconsistent in your  usage of the closing slash on `<meta>`. Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: How will I be able to refresh the content on the Iframe?

Comment: I added this code to my html

     `<body onload="refreshIframe()">
     <script>
        function refreshIframe() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById("example_frame");
            iframe.src = iframe.src; // Reloads the iframe source
           }
        </script>`

But still, sometimes it refresh, sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't refresh, I still need to press ctrl-f5.